# Xamarin.IOS Error - Can not resolve reference: C:/Program Files (x86)/../Xamarin.iOS/v1.0/Facades/System.Private.CoreLib.InteropServices.dll

Tags: android, ios, xamarin.ios

I working on Cross-platform PCL Xamarin Forms (Android,IOS) Project.

I am using Visual Studio 2015 and Window 10 OS to make xamarin project. I have installed Xamarin studio in MAC PC to run IOS project.

My IOS and android project was successfully running but when I update the Xamarin studio in MAC PC it started giving error in ios project:

**Can not resolve reference: C:/Program Files (x86)/Reference Assemblies/Microsoft/Framework/Xamarin.iOS/v1.0/Facades/System.Private.CoreLib.InteropServices.dll**

Please suggest me what to do to solve this error.

Thanks in advance

Comment: dont know the answer but i, getting the same problem today :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem. Installing the latest Xamarin 4.2 Beta fixed in visual studio 2015 for me.
Go to Tools -> Options -> Xamarin -> Other and change the update options to include Beta. I think it installed 4.2.0.680

Answer (score 8):

I was having the same problem until I manually upgraded Xamarin.  In Visual Studio open Tool->Options->Xamarin->Other and select Check Now.  The latest stable release fixed the problem.  Seems the older Xamarin install was not compatible with the Mac install.

Comment: Correct. This happens because of a mismatch between the xamarin version on your mac and windows.